# I can`t solve a passing constant error with my actual knowledge

Tags: c++, c++11

I made a specialization for a bidirectional map when the key type and value type are the same.
Also I made 2 definitions for the `operator[]` ,one to return constant and one to return non constant. But this did not solve my problem.I get an error that i`m passing constant as *this...

Here it is the specialization:

```
template<class A>

class BidirectionalMap<A,A>
{
public:
    void insert(A a,A b)
    {
        m1.insert(std::pair<A,A> (a,b));
        m1.insert(std::pair<A,A> (b,a));
    }
    BidirectionalMap& operator =(BidirectionalMap &a)
    {
        m1=a.m1;
        return *this;
    }
    const A& at(const A& a) const
    {
        return m1.at(a);
    }
    int size() const
    {
        return m1.size();
    }
    int count(const A& a) const
    {
        return m1.count(a);
    }
    A& operator[](const A& a)
    {
        return m1[a];
    }
    const A& operator[](const A& a) const
    {
        return m1[a];////here pinpoints me that error: passing 'const std::map<int, int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> > >' as 'this' argument of 'std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = int; _Tp = int; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = int; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = int]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
    }
private:
    std::map<A,A> m1;
};
```

And the error shows in this context:

```
  BidirectionalMap<int, int> f;
  f.insert(3, 18);
  f.insert(8, 2);
  f.insert(7, 5);
  f.insert(9, 1);
  const BidirectionalMap<int, int> cf = f;

  if( f.at(5) == 7 &&
      f.count(12) == 0 &&
      f.at(8) == 2)
  {
    yourMark = cf[18] + cf[9];//here is the error
  }
```

Any idea?

Comment: See the duplicate. To fix the specific error, you could use `return m1.at(a);`

Comment: Unrelated: a copy constructor usually takes a const reference: `BidirectionalMap& operator =(const BidirectionalMap &a)`, but in your case you don't need one: the compiler generated one will suffice.

Comment: @juanchopanza but this is not a copy constructor...it is an operator..From my knowledge this is a copy constructor : `BidirectionalMap(const BidirectionalMap &a)` no?

Comment: Sorry, I meant *assignment operator*. What I said still applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator[]` is typically not const in std::map
See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/

The reason is that `operator[]` allows to insert if the element is not present.

Comment: And what to do when my bidirectional map is const? It must return a const, no?

Comment: Use at as @juanchopanza indicated (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/at/) or find and iterators if you want to check for existence.